# Solving for a matrix X in a equation ( Beginner linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Hi there I am just wondering if it is valid to solve for one matrix in terms of the other in an equation such as, ( assuming $A,B,C$ are all of size $n \times n$ and invertible, and I is the $n \times n$ identity). Given something like below,

$C^{-1}(B+AX)B^{-1}=I$, then am wondering if the equations I am applying are valid?

$C(C^{-1}(B+AX)B^{-1}B)=I)B$

$=I(B+AX)I=CIB$
$B+AX=CB$
$A^{-1}(AX=CB-B)$
$X=A^{-1}(CB-B)$

Would this be an accurate way to express X? If not what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculations are correct. Indeed, since $A,B,C$ are invertible
$$\begin{align*}I=C^{-1}(B+AX)B^{-1} &\overset{C\cdot|}\implies C=(B+AX)B^{-1} \\&\overset{|\cdot B}\implies CB=B+AX& \\&\implies AX=CB-B \\&\overset{A^{-1}\cdot|}\implies X=A^{-1}(CB-B)=A^{-1}(C-I)B\end{align*}$$